# Microsoft project exceptions

Tags: ms-project

in project 2010 - calendar working time , why the details button is disabled ?

[image]

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a normal behavior, you should first add your `Exceptions` as Name, Start and Finish, then select one of your exceptions. thence you will note that the detail button has been activated as shown below.

[image]

For more details check [Add a resource's vacation/Exceptions time](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Add-a-resource-s-vacation-time-8240adc0-692b-4d23-827b-a81fb560945d?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&fromAR=1)

Comment: Thank you, additional question please? what's your m-project version ? it looks different from my window ?

Comment: It's Microsoft Project Prof 2013. but the same steps would work for you in Microsoft Project Prof 2010, could you please mark my answer as answer if it helped you :)